# How can I get the numbers/elements less than 5 of an array on swift code?

Tags: arrays, swift

My array is this `let numbers = [3, 6, 9, 2, 4, 1]` How can I get the numbers less than 5 of an array on swift code? I try using this

```
let numbers = [3, 6, 9, 2, 4, 1]
var minNumber = 5
for number in numbers {
    minNumber = min(minNumber, number as Int)
}
print("The min numbers are\(minNumber)")
```

But only gives me one number and I need like 1, 2, 3, 4 I don't know if I should sort the array first or if I should just look up the number. I'm sorry if it's a silly question but I'm learning.

I hope someone can help me, I would really appreciate it
link of the photo I'm not allowed to upload: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Odixz.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to create another array and store them in there. Here I use the loop and append the values in the array to minNumbers array. There are many other ways to do this, but this is pretty straightforward.

```
let numbers = [3,6,9,2,4,1]
var minNumbers = [Int]()
var minNumber = 5
for number in numbers {
    if number < minNumber {
        minNumbers.append(number)
    }
}

print("The minimum numbers are: \(minNumbers)")
```

Comment: I don't see why the answer has been downvoted. It's not highlevel, but algorithm is still VERY important in understanding things. Magic highlevel functions & "closures" (with the un-understood `$0` is bad for new developers). I countered the downvote with an upvote.

Comment: I agree that using a closure as an answer is probably not the most appropriate solution for someone new. It is also useful and important to understand but syntactically non intuitive at first.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter(_:)` function of `Array` like this:

```
let numbers = [3,6,9,2,4,1]
var minNumber = 5
let lessThan5 = numbers.filter { $0 < minNumber }
```